# Jquery range slider change background color

Tags: jquery, slider

This is the my code.

```
$(function () {
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [25, 50],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
        console.log(ui.values[1] +'%');
        $('#YourDiv').css('width', 100 - ui.values[1] +'%');
    }
}).append('<div id="YourDiv" style="width: 50%"></div>');

$("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));});
```

Then when i changed the max value to 200 the slider colors are not changing in good order.
So can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that change colors on reaching max value of 200.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        animate: true,
         values: [25, 75],
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').fadeIn();
        },

        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').fadeIn();
        },

        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').text(ui.value+' km/hr');
               $('#YourDiv').css('width', 100 - (ui.values[1]/2) +'%');
        },

        create: function( event, ui ) {
            var tooltip = $('<div class="ui-slider-tooltip" />').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '-28px',
                left: '-1px',
                width:'80px'
            });
            $(event.target).find('.ui-slider-handle').append(tooltip);

            // get handles and set up values
            var firstHandle  = $(event.target).find('.ui-slider-handle')[0];
            var secondHandle = $(event.target).find('.ui-slider-handle')[1];
            firstHandle.firstChild.innerText = 25+' km/hr';
            secondHandle.firstChild.innerText = 75+' km/hr';
        }
```